# org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter: Splitter only returned a single result. If this is not expected, please check your split expression

Tags: mule

I have created a custom java component which reads the JMS Messages in "for loop", removes the duplicate messages based on specific pattern and adds the redundant messages to array list and return this list of messages. In mule configuration, I am using "foreach collection" to iterate through all these messages and run my business logic on these messages one by one.

In logs I am seeing the warning messages "org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter: Splitter only returned a single result. If this is not expected, please check your split expression". When I read the documentation, I found that Mule gives this warning when there is no or only one messages in the collection.

Can anyone help me fixing this warning message?

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to turn this warning off per event or expression splitter instance so your only option is to set the log level for `org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter` to `ERROR`.

Comment: Hello, how can I set mentioed log level?

Comment: @DawidWiniarz See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/logging-in-mule